# PhpStorm reset setting whenever PC automatically restart

Tags: phpstorm, restart

Sometimes during too much of load my PC automatically restart during working so that when I logged in again then it reset my PhpStorm settings.

Does anyone knows how to get rid of this?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. This forum is for programming qustions. Please consider using other stackexchange for this type of question.

Comment: i got this error during programming so that i thing that is best platform to ask question so i ask it.

Comment: thanks for comment

Comment: in that case can you show some code that you might have run before the system crashes? as well as logs

Comment: yes sure it was 10k+ rows and when i get and display on screen it suddenly restart my pc and after that i see that reset my setting so o ask there>

but now i got answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like phpstorm is working as intended. If you shut down your computer suddenly the applications don't have time to save their state correctly and you can get corrupt data. In this case your settings might become corrupt.

If you can't fix your computer (it sounds like a cooling problem) then [export your settings from phpstorm and import them again](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/exporting-and-importing-settings.html) after your computer has restarted.

Comment: Computers shouldn't restart due to "overloading". If they do they likely have a cooling or PSU problem. You may want to mark this as the accepted answer so stack overflow contributors doesn't spend extra time going over this question in the future not knowing that it's already resolved.

Comment: Below the down vote arrow to the left of the post there is a check mark you can click.